# Как создать Kodachi Encrypted live USB

Tags: linux, ubuntu, live-usb

Создатель Kodachi утверждает, что 100% безопасности можно добиться только если у вас будет закриптованная live usb. Я пытался установить kodachi на флешку, но тогда это уже не будет live usb. При запуске kodachi с загрузочной флешки выбирал “kodachi encrypted persistent”, но происходил обычный запуск рабочего стола, где предлагалось снова просто установить kodachi, то есть система не была encrypted. Вопрос заключается в том, как сделать encrypted live usb

Comment: ну, уточните у «создателя», как вам быть. наверняка ведь он не только изречением разных утверждений занимался, но и документацию какую-нибудь написал.

Comment: Гуглил документации и всё остальное. Именно по kodachi ответа нет. Видел способ с kali Linux, но он не подходит

Comment: А чем `tails` не устроил?